# Replace placeholder 1 character at a time in html/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an input field for the tire size of a car. The placeholder for this is `___/__ R__`

When I click the input field I'd like to have the cursor start at the beginning of that placeholder. When I type the placeholder should be replaced 1 character at a time. When the first 3 numbers are typed in, it has to go to the next underscore. The `/`, space and `R` has to stay.

Is there a way I can do this with jQuery and HTML?

Comment: Can you post the code as well? We generally don't want to do your homework for you - show what you have done so far. The `<>` button can create a runnable snippet.

Comment: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: @PeterKrebs i'm sorry, i understand that it would be helpful to post the created code as well, but the problem is i dont know where to start, so thats why i dont have any code yet. I only have an input in html: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tireSize" id="tireSize" autocomplete="off" required>

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you, that is what i was searching for!

Comment: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/PbOEqL